# How to measure bandwidth of cell module and AT-commands

Tags: http, terminal, sms, gsm, at-command

Im attempting to make http requests using my LTE/GSM module (Quectel EC-21) to eventually test bandwidth. Im fairly new to AT commands and I've set up an APN. Now I'm trying to AT+HTTPINIT but am constantly receiving errors. Can anyone point me to a tutorial that demonstrates how to initialize http and put the connection to use? I feel like I may have missed setting something up before doing the about AT command.

Answer (score 1):

I've not found any guide about `+HTTPINIT` command, but probably what you need is to read carefully the specific HTTP(s) guide I easily found on internet for EC-2x family.

https://sixfab.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Quectel_EC2xEG9xEM05_HTTPS_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.0.pdf

It seems to be a complete guide, since after some introduction it starts listing the preliminary settings (such as setting APN and raising up a PDP context). Each command is described widely, and example/error handling sections should help you even you are new to this set of commands.